# firestore where array doesn't contain

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to fetch documents from firestore where document array doesn't contain auth.currentUser.uid.

I have collection groups. There are a lot of groups inside the collection. I want to fetch groups of which I am not a member.

Comment: There is no `array-does-not-contain` operator in Firestore. You will have to load all groups and then filter them client-side.

Comment: Loading all groups is going to be expensive...

Comment: Any alternative solution?